# 1. passing constant object to a structure & 2. delete pointer element in vector, but not object its pointing to

Tags: c++

For certain objects (elements) in the vector `aArray`, I want to create a mininum sorted heap.

1. I want to modify the members of `aArray` in other functions and call `Heap` member functions to update the min heap. This means that I should pass in a constant vector to the `Heap` structure, but I am having a lot of trouble with this am being swamped with errors. What is the proper way to pass constant objects to `Heap` constructor?
2. Also, when I call the function `popHeap`, I want to delete only the pointer to the root in the heap, but it deletes the object in vector `aArray` also. How can I fix this?

   ```
   #include <vector>
   #include <iostream>

   struct A
   {
       A(int av, int bv):a(av),b(bv){}
       int a, b;
   };

   struct Heap
   {
      Heap() : ptr(new std::vector<A>()) {}

      Heap(std::vector<A> *p) : ptr(p) {}

      void makeHeap()
      { // some code here }

      void popHeap()
      {
          ptr->erase(ptr.begin()+heapLoc[0]);  //DELETES aArray member! I only want to delete the pointer, not the object. 
          //some code here   
      }

      std::vector<A> *ptr;
      std::vector<int> heapLoc;
   };


   int main()
   {
        A a0(2,5), a1(4,2), a2(8,4), a3(0,3);  
        std::vector<A> aArray;  
        aArray.push_back(a0);  aArray.push_back(a1);  aArray.push_back(a2);   aArray.push_back(a3);

        for(int i=0; i<aArray.size(); ++i)
        {
           std::cout << "aArray[i].a = " << aArray[i].a << " "
                     << "aArray[i].b = " << aArray[i].b <<  "\n";
        } //All 4 objects outputted

        Heap h(&aArray);
        h.makeHeap();

        h.popHeap();

        for(int i=0; i<aArray.size(); ++i)
        {
           std::cout << "aArray[i].a = " << aArray[i].a << " "
                     << "aArray[i].b = " << aArray[i].b <<  "\n";
        } //Only 3 objects outputted. One gets deletated. 
   }
   ```

Comment: "DELETES aArray member" No, the vector holds `A` elements by value, so it doesn't `delete` anything, the object is destroyed. You may be thinking that `vector<A>` will behave like `vector<A*>`, but that's not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the entire passed vector in the constructor (don't just have a pointer to it). Allowing anything to modify the internal structure of something that needs to have a specific structure (as in sorted elements) to work is a bad idea. You can do this simply as follows:

```
class Heap
{
   ...
   Heap(std::vector<A> &input): vect(input) { };
   std::vector<A> vect;
}
```

You will need to either have a copy constructor or override the `=` operator for A for the above to work, but doing both doesn't hurt. As in:

```
class A
{
   ...
   A(const A &o): a(o.a), b(o.b) {}; // Copy constructor
   void operator=(const A &o): a(o.a), b(o.b) {}; // = operator
}
```

Adding both pieces of code will copy all the elements in the vector in the heap's constructor. Pointers won't work for this since are always be shallow-copied, unless you explicitly deep-copy them, which is a bit more effort.

An alternative to this is always starting with an empty heap and having an `add` method (still not using pointers).

If you don't want to copy elements, you can use the `const` keyword. As in use `const A` everywhere in your code where you used `A`.

Note 1 - I'd suggest getting rid of the makeHeap method and just doing that work in the constructor.

Note 2 - I used `class` above, and not `struct`. Don't use `struct` in C++, use `class` instead. `struct` is more C.